# Disable step into designer.cs while debugging windows forms in visual studio. 2022

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am facing a problem while stepping into dotnet 4.8 windows forms solution. The problem is that when I step into a break point it will step into Generated Code such as dataset.designer.cs and designer.cs

This behavior makes my debugging session for a huge solution with hundreds of projects impossible because how long stepping into so many code that is not my code.

I can reproduce the problem by:

- Create a new Windows Forms .Net Framework Solution.
- Add a Button to Form1.
- Add Form2 to the project.

Write the following code in Button_Click Event:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

When I add a break point in `form2.Show()` line then step into it, the debugger will go into Form2.Designer.cs, that what I do not want.

Please do not tell me to step over because I want to be redirected to wcf code in the main solution.

I remember that this problem I faced when I installed visual studio 2019 in a new laptop several years ago. Unfortunately, I do not remember how I fixed it!

Now I have Visual Studio 2022 and I am struggling in this issue. I can confirm that "Enable Just My Code" is checked and "Load only specified code" is checked.

I tried to delete .vs fold as well, but still visual studio is keeping stepping into generated code.

I want to step into my code only and ignore all generated code. How to do that?